# datetime comparison in if clause

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have the following code:

```
%if "&min_date"dt <= "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt %then %do;
  /* some code */
%end
```

And it doesn't behave as I expect.

My `min_date` is inferior but the tested expression is evaluated to `0`

```
%put &min_date; /* 31JAN1600:00:00:00 */
%put %eval("&min_date"dt <= "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt); /* 0 */
%put %eval("31JAN1600:00:00:00"dt <= "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt); /* 0 */
```

How do I make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have shown, %EVAL does not know about date-time literals, so it sees them as string values.  Since %EVAL is called implicitly by an %IF statement. the %IF statement does a text comparison instead of numeric comparison.

The good news is %SYSEVALF **does** know about date-time literals:

```
%let min_date = 31JAN1600:00:00:00 ; 
%put %sysevalf("&min_date"dt) ;   /*-11357884800*/
%put %sysevalf("&min_date"dt <= "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt);  /* 1 */
%put %sysevalf("31JAN1600:00:00:00"dt <= "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt); /* 1 */
```

In a macro %IF:

```
%macro test(min_date=) ;
  %if %sysevalf("&min_date"dt <= "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt) %then %do;
    %put &min_date is less than or equal to "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt ;
  %end ;
  %else %do ;
    %put &min_date is NOT less than or equal to "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt ;
  %end ;
%mend ;
```

Which returns log like:

```
124  %test(min_date=31JAN1600:00:00:00)
31JAN1600:00:00:00 is less than or equal to "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt
125  %test(min_date=31JAN2015:00:00:00)
31JAN2015:00:00:00 is NOT less than or equal to "02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, %EVAL() did "work" in your example. :) Not as intended, but here's why:

- First, %EVAL() checks if the operands can be evaluated as either arithmetic (integer only) or logical.
- Because you provided 2 datetime literals which contained non-integer characters, it performed a logical comparison based on the character sort sequence.

%SYSEVALF() - as mentioned previously - will work because, unlike %EVAL(), it supports non-integer characters as operands with an additional evaluation thereof.

This is how %SYSEVALF() supports floating point arithmetic, whereas %EVAL() can only support integer.

BTW, %EVAL() is also used to evaluate expressions in a %IF or %DO statement etc - which is why datetime literals are also not supported in these cases.

NB: bearing the above in mind, it's generally good practice to:

- for integer arithmetic, use %EVAL()
- for floating point arithmetic, use %SYSEVAL()
- always convert datetime literals to an integer, as in the answer above, with %sysfunc(inputn(&datetimeliteral,datetimex.))

where x will vary according to the datetime literal...

Answer (score 0):

Even when you're using literals, I think the macro environment treats the values being compared as strings - it does not try to resolve the literals to the underlying numeric values before performing the comparison. If you want the comparison to work as expected, you have to convert the dates into something that the macro language can compare as a number, e.g.

```
%put %eval(%sysfunc(putn("&min_date"dt,16.)) <= %sysfunc(putn("02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt,16.)));
```

Alternatively, you can temporarily step out of the macro language and then you can use the literals directly, e.g.:

```
%put %eval(%sysfunc(intck(second,"&min_date"dt,"02DEC2014:00:00:00"dt)) > 0);
```